# Trying to have 2 drop down boxes point to a URL

Tags: html

So I am trying to have a page on my site that contains 2 drop down boxes and a submit button. The submit button will point to a URL when clicked and then that will take them to a new page.
The URL will be based on whatever is selected in the drop down menus.

For example:
Drop down 1 has options A and B
Drop down 2 has options 1 and 2

Then there would be a different url for each combination
A1 points to URL-1
A2 points to URL-2
B1 points to URL-3
B2 points to URL-4

I really don't know much about coding and have been searching for a way to do this for the last 3 hours and I just don't even know how to google it. I really appreciate any help I can get at this point. Thank you in advance! :)

Here is the code from my drop boxes. I edited the options to match the example with the A, B, 1, and 2.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<select id="list1t">
  <option>Select one</option>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
</form>
<form>
<select id="list2">
  <option>Select one</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste your code than select it than press ctrl + K you will able to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
var url;
$(function(){
$('#link').click(function(){
    var val1=$('#first').val();
    var val2=$('#second').val();
    if(val1=='A'){
        if(val2=='1'){
              url="URL1";
        }
        else{
              url="URL2";
        }
    }else{
        if(val2=='1'){
              url="URL3";
        }
        else{
              url="URL4";
        }
    }
    window.location.href=url;
});
});
</script>
```

the html would be

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

you can use a link for clicking . no need of form or submit button

```
<a href="#" id="link">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: This would work, except you did not mention that this requires jQuery. Since the OP mentioned he is new to coding, he probably would not recognize the syntax and so it is important to mention this. The question is also tagged JavaScript, so I would think a JS-only solution would be preferred (although I could be wrong).

Comment: I think I can only use HTML

Comment: Well it works, but I am struggling to figure out how to actually edit it for use with my code and website. I have the drop down boxes showing my options, but I am not sure how to have the URL change when different options are selected in the drop down. It never changes from the sites base URL + #.